# Select and Groupby in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How can i use this script in laravel controller?

```
 SELECT MAX(branch_tbl.branch_name) AS Branch_Name, COUNT(staffinfo.branchID) AS Count_Branch
    FROM branch_tbl
    LEFT JOIN staffinfo ON staffinfo.branchID = branch_tbl.branch_id
    GROUP BY branch_tbl.branch_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of it so

```
DB::table('branch_tbl')->select(DB::raw('MAX(branch_tbl.branch_name) AS Branch_Name, COUNT(branch_tbl.branch_id) AS Count_Branch'))
    ->leftJoin('staffinfo', 'staffinfo.branchID', '=', 'branch_tbl.branch_id')
    ->groupBy('branch_tbl.branch_id')->get()
```